# How to insert Thymeleaf fragment conditionally?

Tags: thymeleaf

Given is a basic layout template, which is called by individual page templates. Fragments are passed as parameters.

What I want to achieve is that if no footer fragment is passed to layout.html (in this example by index.html), a default footer shall be used.

According to Thymeleaf's documentation you can omit passing fragments either using empty fragments or the no-operation token: [conditional insertion of fragments](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#advanced-conditional-insertion-of-fragments)

Unfortunately, a check inside the layout.html template whether a valid fragment or an empty one was passed does not seem to work, at least not as shown in the following example.

For illustration here stripped versions of layout, index and footer:

layout.html:

```java
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      th:fragment="layout(footer)">

<head></head>

<body>

    <footer th:replace="${footer} ?: ~{includes/footer :: footer}"></footer>

</body>
</html>
```

footer.html:

```java
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<footer th:fragment="footer">

    <div>Aloha from Hawaii</div>

</footer>

</html>
```

index.html:

```java
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      th:replace="~{layout :: layout(_)}">

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The code `<footer th:replace="${footer} ?: ~{includes/footer :: footer}">` always replaces the footer with the passed fragment, no matter whether this passed fragment is valid or empty, which in case of an empty fragment results in no footer being displayed at all. A check for null (or emptiness) doesn't seem to work this way.

Can someone please tell me how to check inside layout.html if the submitted footer fragment is empty, and in case it is, how then to insert the default footer?

**Many thanks for any help**

#### Edit

After some trial and error and lot of coffee I came up with a working solution, although it feels a little like a hack, rather than fine artist. Thymeleaf is definitely able to distinguish between an empty fragment and one with content inside - though Thymeleaf won't share this feature with the rest of the world. However, we can take advantage of this as follows:

```java
<th:block th:replace="${footer}">
    <footer th:replace="~{includes/footer :: footer}"></footer>
</th:block>
```

This way, the middle line will always claim the standard footer, while the block will only replace its content when a valid footer-property is passed. Voila, time for cookies.